# Is there a Novatel Wireless Modem Emulator or something similar?

Tags: emulation, modem

Novatel Wireless provides their NovaCore SDK for developers wishing to interface with their line of modems. I'm currently developing an open source managed wrapper for it, but I'm having difficulties with testing. I own a Novatel MiFi and have mobile broadband service through Sprint, but that can only get me so far. The device is already activated, thus I can't test the network activation features of the NovaCore SDK. There are also certain features only available for HSPA modems, which I am not able to get in my area.

Is there an emulator capable of emulating a Novatel Wireless modem so that I can test my library without physical hardware and an actual data connection? If not, do you have any other suggestions that might help in this situation?

I've contacted Novatel Wireless via email and their developer forum, but have not received a response.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm developing on Windows at the moment, but if there's something specific to Linux, I don't have a problem with switching.

Comment: They are super slow to respond. I just downloaded the windows SDK and am having problems with it (sdk.isLoaded returns false even though the nvtlserver is running). The SDK documentation is out of date and no one responds on the forums.

Comment: Indeed. I gave up a long time ago. The SDK was failing at a different place each time I ran my test application and Novatel wouldn't respond to my questions. :(